# Keep timer (setInterval) running while reloading page

Tags: javascript

Once I load a webpage, I insert some Javscript via the console. I was wondering if it's possible for me to, using either Javascript or jQuery, reload the page (not from cache) while keeping a setInterval that I have running. I'm familiar with location.reload(), but that terminates it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you reload a page, the entire page context including all running JS is completely destroyed.  You cannot keep a `setInterval()` running while its host page is reloaded.

You can create a signal for the new page to start the interval going again itself using a cookie, query parameter or local storage value (query parameter is probably the most appropriate).  If you go this way, then you need to code the page to look for a specific query parameter and if it finds it, then the page should start the designated `setInterval()` itself.  You can even pass some data in the query parameter (such as how much more time until the next interval should fire, etc...).

Another option is to not actually reload the page, but instead to refresh the content manually by getting new content via an ajax call and then inserting it into the current page.  This allowed the current page context and running interval timers to continue running.

Comment: @Ryan - you set a cookie before the reload.  Then, when the page reloads, you check for the existence of the cookie and if you find it, you start the interval timer and then remove the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible unless you fetch the page using Ajax request,  then replace the body while the setInterval Is working