# setInterval stops after reload browser

Tags: angular, setinterval

I'm making auto-logout feature in Angular.
So I use `setInterval` for this, but, `setInterval` doesn't work after reloading the browser. I mean the timer disappears after reloading.
If not reload, everything is fine.
If you have any ideas to resolve this issue, please reply to me. Thank you.
Here's my code

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.check();
      }, CHECK_INTERVALL);
    })
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by "the timer disappears after reloading". Do you mean that running that code again after reloading the browser doesn't start the timer? Or do you expect the timer that you started once to keep running after reloading the browser? In the latter case, your question is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23037049/1009922).